# Why would all of the javascript tags ("type=text/javascript") in a WordPress site be assigned random alphanumerics?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, random, alphanumeric

So, I've never seen this before and can't find documentation on this. There is a randomly generated code associated with each of the javascripts running on a WordPress site I am working on. I have no idea what is generating this, but it could be causing some javascript conflicts.

It appears like this:

```
<script type="f9dacaae4ee41613fcbad81d-text/javascript">//
```

The alphanumeric code is random but it is applied to all of the "script type"s on the page. When you refresh the page, a new code is applied.

It doesn't happen in staging, only on the live site. Is this cloudfare?

Comment: It means that the script tag contents are executed manually for some reason, though I can't think of why there'd be random text as well. Seems like a peculiar setup.

Comment: Thanks (and thanks for the edit kiranvj), I can't think of a reason either. I always think the worst when I see things like this.

Comment: I am not seeing it my wordpress site. Maybe one of the plugins in your site is adding it. One way to find it to search this random string in entire source `Ctrl+Shift+f` in Chrome dev tools. This way we know where this is used.

Comment: Disable Rocket Loader on CloudFlare.

yourdomain.com > Speed > Optimization: